# How do I use Path Matcher for front page?

Tags: 8

I have used the following code in a Drupal 8 theme file.

```
$current_path = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
$path_alias = Unicode::strtolower(\Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path));
$visiblity = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->matchPath($path_alias, $pages);
```

`$pages` contains values like `'<front>'` or `'/blog'`.

`$visiblity` is set to `FALSE` for /, but to `TRUE` for /node; Both are the front page.

What is the wrong with my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is assuming that the request URI for / will retrieve /node on the `getAliasByPath()` method call. It won't. Setting the Drupal front page isn't the same as setting a path alias in the Path module.

Use the following code, which will return Drupal's internal /node path even on / requests.

```
$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
```